Query not accepting my newly created "as YearMonth" column when I use Group By function
UsingSQL Server
SELECT FORMAT ( ActionDate , 'yyyy-MM' ) as YearMonth, count(*) as 'Amount'
            FROM [My_view_with_dates]
            Group By 'YearMonth'

I am trying to Group By the YearMonths together and count how many fall under that newly created column. But I am getting the error

Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

It doesn't want to group by the newly created YearMonth column.
Side note: I CAN group by ActionDate, but it doesn't group them right. Each count is 1.
Any ideas?
I've tried changing some of the syntax, as well as grouping by the original column name "ActionDate" but this doesn't work because I need the YYYY-M format.

You can't group by a column alias, your either have to group by the same expression, or use a sub-query.

Points to note, don't single quote aliases, its not the correct delimiter, and it fails in some circumstances, use either "" or []. Also FORMAT is very slow. Use CONVERT + SUBSTRING if you can.

Wow thanks for the quick response! That worked. I thought the alias would have worked, not the original expression. Thanks

Hopefully you also have an upgrade path mapped out to get your SQL Server to a supported version?

@DaleK I'm on 2019, I'm not sure why the tag is referencing 2008. Typo.

You can edit it.

To expand on Dale's comment, CONVERT(CHAR(7), ActionDate, 23) as YearMonth could improve performance.

You can use a CROSS APPLY.   This method allows you to stack and reference derived values
SELECT YearMonth
      ,count(*) as [Amount]
FROM [My_view_with_dates] 
CROSS APPLY ( values ( FORMAT( ActionDate , 'yyyy-MM' ) ) ) B(YearMonth)
Group By [YearMonth]


This is a clear dup... the world doesn't need any more answers saying the same thing :)

@DaleK  No doubt.   I just feel some need a little nudge working with their structure.

@JohnCappelletti - Interestingly, the linked question does not have an answer that uses the CROSS APPLY approach, which I believe is better than the accepted answer that duplicates the calculation multiple times.

It has a cross apply answer now :)
